# RewriteRule URL User-friendly profile link creation

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create user-friendly URLs for my users profiles. For example, elena93, is a user. And to go to her profile, you can simply go to: `http://mysite.com/elena93`

I know how to achieve this using htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)$ user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The above code works, but the problem is, I have rewritten urls for other pages too. Like, home.php can be accessed using `http://mysite.com/home`, messages.php can be accessed using `http://mysite.com/messages`. When I set up the user-friendly profile links, rewritten urls for home, messages, etc pages stops working.

How do I fix that? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, deleted the answer and upvoted. Was a long shot, the way I'd managed to overcome a similar problem, but such scenarios are almost never the same :(

Comment: You need to think about the order of your rules, and which is most specific. Since this pattern matches absolutely any single "word", it will also match "home" and "messages". Without the full contents of your configuration, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: @JohanLevitt let me know if my answer works for u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^//]+)$ user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That will exclude existing files.